# xml appending issue

Tags: jquery, appendchild

Any one help me?

i have the xml with 2 steps. example :

```
<listgroup title="Lifestyle" shortnote="">

  <list>Type of Company: Architects may be self-employed.</list>
  <list>Workspace – Indoors/outdoors: Architects work both.</list>
  <list>Environment
   <sublistgroup>
    <sublist>Travel: Architects often visit construction sites to review the progress of projects.</sublist>
    <sublist>People: They work a lot with other professionals involved in the construction project including engineers, contractors, surveyors and landscape architects.</sublist>
    <sublist>Casual: They usually work in a casual and comfortable environment.</sublist>
    <sublist>Hours: The hours are varied based on the project they are working on.</sublist>
    <sublist>Physically demanding: They stand on their feet.</sublist>
    <sublist>Tools: Computers - Architects </sublist>
   </sublistgroup>
  </list>
  <list>Assist clients in obtaining construction bids</list>
  <list>Observe, inspect and monitor building work</list>
```

in my funcation i am using "list.each" to append to ul+index. it works fine. And my problem is while i append the "list.each", the "sublistgroup" should not append to "list.each", insted the "sublistgroup" need to make "ul" and in the ul i need the "sublist" became childrens..

my code is here...

i konw that, i am doing some wrong way.. pls any one correct it and let me know..

```
$(function(){
    $.get('career-utility.xml',function(myData){

    $(myData).find('listgroup').each(function(index){
          var count = index;
          var listGroup = $(this);
          var listGroupTitle = $(this).attr('title');
          var shortNote =   $(this).attr('shortnote');
          var subLink   = $(this).find('sublist');
          var firstList = $(this).find('list');

           $('.grouplist').append('<div class="list-group"><h3>'+listGroupTitle+'</h3><ul class="level-one level' + count + '"></ul></div>');

            firstList.each(function(listnum){
                var subList = $(this).text();

                var subListLeveltwo = $(this).find('sublist').text();

                if(subListLeveltwo==''){
                    $('<li>'+subList+'</li>').appendTo('ul.level'+count+'');
                }
                else{
                    $('<li class="new">'+subList+'</li>').appendTo('ul.level'+count+'');
                }

            })

    })



    })    
})
```

Comment: Could you provide (short) examples of the input and expected output XML documents?

Comment: You have not accepted any answers to the questions you've asked. You should go back and accept answers that were helpful by clicking the checkmark next to an answer. Click here to review your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/218349/3gwebtrain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution that will re-use the existing XML structure.

It's a bit shorter.

```
$.get('career-utility.xml',function(myData){

    $(myData).find('listgroup').each(function(index){

      var count = index;
      var listGroup = $(this);
      var listGroupTitle = $(this).attr('title');
      var shortNote =   $(this).attr('shortnote');
      var subLink   = $(this).find('sublist');
      var firstList = $(this).find('list');

       $('.grouplist').append('<div class="list-group"><h3>'+listGroupTitle+'</h3><ul class="level-one level' + count + '"></ul></div>');

        firstList.each(function(listnum) {
             // This simply wraps the content of existing XML nodes,
             //   then unwraps the old node
            $(this).wrapInner('<li>')
                   .find('sublistgroup').wrapInner('<ul>').children().unwrap()
                   .find('sublist').wrapInner('<li>').children().unwrap();

               // Append content of 'list' node
            $('ul.level'+count).append($(this).children());  

        });
    });
});
```

It produces the same result, with less code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to create a nested `<ul>` list when you come across a `sublistgroup`.

If so, try this:

```
$.get('career-utility.xml',function(myData){

    $(myData).find('listgroup').each(function(index){

      var count = index;
      var listGroup = $(this);
      var listGroupTitle = $(this).attr('title');
      var shortNote =   $(this).attr('shortnote');
      var subLink   = $(this).find('sublist');
      var firstList = $(this).find('list');

       $('.grouplist').append('<div class="list-group"><h3>'+listGroupTitle+'</h3><ul class="level-one level' + count + '"></ul></div>');

            // Cache the current UL for performance
       var $currentUL = $('ul.level'+count);

        firstList.each(function(listnum) {

            var $subListGroup = $(this).find('sublistgroup').remove();

            var listHeading = $(this).text();

            $currentUL.append('<li>'+listHeading+'</li>');

            if($subListGroup.length){

                   // Cache the new UL for the sub group, and append to the currentUL
                var $subUL = $('<ul class="sublevel' + count + '"></ul>').appendTo( $currentUL );

                $subListGroup.children('sublist').each(function() {
                    $subUL.append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>')
                });
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Should produce the following HTML:

```
<div class="grouplist">
    <div class="list-group">
        <h3>Lifestyle</h3>
        <ul class="level-one level0">
            <li>Type of Company: Architects may be self-employed.</li>
            <li>Workspace &ndash; Indoors/outdoors: Architects work both.</li>
            <li>Environment</li>
            <ul class="sublevel0">
                <li>Travel: Architects often visit construction sites to review the progress of projects.</li>
                <li>People: They work a lot with other professionals involved in the construction project including engineers, contractors, surveyors and landscape architects.</li>
                <li>Casual: They usually work in a casual and comfortable environment.</li>
                <li>Hours: The hours are varied based on the project they are working on.</li>
                <li>Physically demanding: They stand on their feet.</li>
                <li>Tools: Computers - Architects </li>
            </ul>
            <li>Assist clients in obtaining construction bids</li>
            <li>Observe, inspect and monitor building work</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```